# Socket.io reconnection causes new username

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat

I am creating a chat in `node.js` and `socket.io`.

When a user opens my application, I ping the server and ask it to let the user join a specific room and set a random username (which can be edited at a later stage).

I use this

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('join room', (roomId, callback) => {
    // leave and join room
    if (socket.roomId) {
      socket.leave(socket.roomId);
    }
    socket.roomId = roomId;
    socket.join(roomId);

    // set username
    if (!socket.username) {
      socket.username = getRandomUsername();
    }
  });

});
```

It seems to work, but I have experienced situation where I have had the application running for a long time, and suddenly the user's username has changed.

I am suspecting this to occur because the user has lost connection, and `socket.io` have tried reconnecting. When the user has reconnected, the original socket is lost (and therefore it has no username), and a new username is assigned to the new socket, which overrides the original client socket.

Is there a problem with my code by assigning a random username to the user like this? It is somehow the same Google Docs does when the user is not signed in (they often give you an animal's name).

How can I solve the problem? I would very much like to avoid using cookies. An option could probably be to tell the client that it lost connection, and it has to reload the page, and then ask the server to get the same username.

I already save the assigned username on the client with this code:

```
const socket = io();

let username = null;

socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('join room', roomId, function (newUsername) {
    username = newUsername;
  });
});

(...)
```

Comment: You might want to try to listen to the `reconnect` event, and see if it is indeed fired. If you find that re-connection really is the issue, you might want to create a `rejoin room` event that receives the saved username from the client

Comment: You pretty much have to use either a cookie or a consistently generated query parameter when socket.io connects to identify a particular user.  Cookies are used for this 99.9999% of the time.  Why is it you don't want to use the easy way of identifying a user if/when they reconnect?  You don't have to put the username in the cookie.  You could just use a session ID and have the username stored in the server if you don't want users to be able to mess with user names.